# xcode interfacebuilder Objects linked to custom class in Inspector?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

In Xcode(latest version) Interfacebuilder, you can link objects to code.

I have created one a class: @interface FileChangeController : NSObject

But it is not listed in custom class, in Interfacebuilder Inspector?

Do you have to do something special?

Thanks in advance
Regards
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subclass from UI* classes for that to appear in the inspector. For example:

```
@interface FileChangeController : UIViewController
```

That should make it visible in the inspector.

[image: Custom Class Inspector]

Also, it will be visible only for the relevant control. That is UIViewController classes will only be visible for view controller (duh!) objects.

Comment: Thank you - I thought that yo could use a proxy object for NSObject. One of the object in "Object library" is called Object and the description says: Provides an instance of an NSObject subclass that is not available in Interface Builder.  You can use this object to create instances of your own classes?

Comment: Yes you can. For more details, see here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles/CustomObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009971-CH9-SW1 This has a video that shows how to do it.

Comment: It is an IB bug - just found out that I can debug into "init()" if I just type in the Class Name, not caring if IB will find it in the drop down list. The bug is that the Class is not shown in the dorp down list, but it works at runtime. I will give you credit for trying to understanding my question :-)

Comment: Oh. :) Then part of my question is true at least. About the 'relevant control' part. I have noticed that I can add other classes too which are not listed but it can crash in case of some incompatibility.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have properly linked your view controller class to the interface builder view controller

[image]

Then using the assistant editor, you can drag the connection directly to code.

[image]

Comment: I don't think he is asking about how to create the actions and link an object to a custom class. He is confused about why it doesn't show up in the custom class inspector.