# UIScrollView not responding to delegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I used to have my `UIView` that worked fine with several delegates some of them below. Now I changed that `UIView` from `IB` to be a `UIScrollView` (Now used as main view).

Since I've changed to `UIScrollView` my event delegates such as those below dont work anymore. Such as keyboard and also I had an element that I could move around and not it is just static.

I assigned all delegates form the IB that I could think of and did most things that I know. but i am running out of ideas on why the events are not getting triggered....

if i go back to the old `UIView` by doing `cmd + z` they work.

Could anyone point me in the right direction??

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{

   [self.view endEditing:TRUE];
}
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView { 
    // register for keyboard notifications

    return YES;
}
```

**EDIT - Complementary answer:**

`@Wezly` Answer is totally valid. 
 But if anyone doesn't want to subclass the `UIScrollView` and use only `UITextFieldDelegate` methods.

another way of doing it is adding to `viewDidLoad`:

Note: you still cant access many things, but its another workaround

```
///
/// DelegateNotifications
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:self.view.window];
// register for keyboard notifications
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:self.view.window];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(textFieldDidEndEditing:)
                                             name:UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification
                                           object:self.view.window];
```

Comment: Have you declared <UIScrollViewDelegate> ?

Comment: yes.` @interface myProfileEditController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate,UITextViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate>`

Comment: A *delegate* is an object, not a method. If you're talking about a method that a delegate is expected to respond to, use *delegate method*. If you're talking about the interface to which a delegate conforms, use *delegate protocol* or *delegate interface*.

Comment: @sangony That doesn't matter.

Comment: @OP: Have you set your delegate? `scrollView.delegate = self;`

Comment: @H2CO3 yes, I've done that

Comment: Your problem is that your `UIScrollView` is cancelling touches on your `viewController` - The way I got around this was to subclass `UIScrollView` and then move the touch event in to the subclass.

Comment: @Wezly but surely it Wouldn't stop the UITextFieldDelegate?

Comment: Make your scroll view smaller and move your textfield outside the scrollView in IB to see what happens.

Comment: @Wezly True, you are right. What do you mean by subclass UIScrollView. Create an object that has all my information without IB?

Comment: @Wezly in another view I got it to work... just like this, thats why I dont know why is not working now

Comment: You got it.. Looks like you can link to the subclass from interface builder too so you wouldn't have to change much, see here - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303767/xcode-interfacebuilder-objects-linked-to-custom-class-in-inspector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303767/xcode-interfacebuilder-objects-linked-to-custom-class-in-inspector)

Comment: Its easier if i just add the the notifications manualy

Comment: @JonathanThurft I’ve noticed you’ve been using the cocoa tag for your Cocoa Touch questions, but that tag is for Cocoa (OS X) questions only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you subclass your UIScrollView object and add your touch events inside of it like below..

canvasObject.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface canvasObject : UIScrollView 

@end
```

canvasObject.m

```
#import "canvasObject.h"

@implementation canvasObject

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    self.canCancelContentTouches = false;
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
  //Do Stuff
}

- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView { 
  return YES;
}

@end
```

Then link your `UIScrollView` using the identity inspector in interface builder to the new scroll view subclass like below..

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to access the properties in the scrollview from the subclass or notifications is the only way?

Comment: Have you tried using an `IBOutlet` you may need to import the new subclass in to the viewController.h - `IBOutlet canvasObject *canvas;`