# Is it possible to access a property in the superclass from a subclass that belong to subclassed element?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am `sub-classing` a `UIScrollView element` in response to a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179446/uiscrollview-not-responding-to-delegates) question suggestion.

In my `subclass` I have a few methods that are triggered by touch and keyboard events. Those events need to interact in various ways with variables that are in my `superview`.

I've tried accessing them via `_myVar.text = @"smth"` but that doesnt compile.

I know I could play back and forth with `NSNotifications` but is there a way to access the variables in my `superview / class` from my `UISCrollView` `subclass`?

I've tried `self.myVar = @""` but it says that it is not recgonised. I am subclassing an `UIScrollView element` but then my view that hold all my variables is a `UIViewController`. just the UISCroll element was subclassed

Answer (score 0):

Everything that is a `@property` in your superclass is accessible in your subclass, but not in the other way

Comment: when I go _myVar in my subclass it doesn't compile

Comment: @JonathanThurft Because that's an instance variable and not a property. No need to downvote if your knowledge is insufficient to understand the answer.

Comment: @H2CO3 I didn't downgrade. But I've accessing properties that are declared with `@property` using `_myVar` from my `UIScroller` subview and it didnt work

Comment: @JonathanThurft It doesn't have to work either. Properties are to be accessed using the **accessor** methods (or the dot syntax, which is just syntactic sugar for the former).

Comment: @H2CO3 I've tried `self.myVar = @""` but it says that it is not recgonised. I am subclassing an `UIScrollView element` but then my view that hold all my variables is a `UIViewController`. just the `UISCroll element` was subclassed in the `IB`. btw did you downvote me?

Comment: Can you add please your header file of your UIScrollView subclass.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're a little confused here. Are you sure you're talking about the superview?  Or are you talking about the superclass from which you derived your subclass? If superview, and if you know the type of the superview, get a pointer to it, cast it to the appropriate class type, then call methods on it or access its visible properties.

```
UIButton* superButton = (UIButton*)[self superview];
superButton.visible = NO; // Assign to superview property
```

If you're talking about the superclass (in your case `UIScrollView`), then yes of course you can use any of its visible methods and properties.

```
self.bounces = YES; // Assign to superclass property
```

In case it's not clear what the difference is, you should really do some more reading about the basics of Objective-C and object oriented programming.

- Superview: the view relative to which this view is laid out. This view is a `subview` of the superview. `UIView` and all derived classes have this hierarchical relationship.
- Superclass: the class whose functionality you are extending to define your subclass. Your subclass inherits all visible properties and methods.

Comment: I am subclassing an element `UIScrollView` so that it handless event triggers. So all functionality is in my main class which is a `UIViewController`

Comment: Generally you shouldn't try to access the `UIViewController` that owns a view from the `UIView` (or a subclass of some type of `UIView`). That's why it's got 'controller' in the name--it should be doing the controlling (but there are detailed justifications for this rule). If you're trying to recognize taps on a `UIScrollView`, try using `UITapGestureRecognizer` from the `UIViewController` and attach it to the `UIScrollView`. I couldn't find the other question where people told you to do what you're trying to do now, but I don't think they gave you good advice.

Comment: @IdIes `UIScrollView` cancell the touch  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179446/uiscrollview-not-responding-to-delegates

Comment: I'm still not clear from that question what you're trying to accomplish. Explain to me what you want to happen when the user interacts with the UIScrollView.

Comment: Basically I am putting my `UIKeyboardNotification` (hide | show) in my subclass. Then I will play with it so that the `InputFields` are displayed always above the keyboard. Given that the notification handler is in the subclass and I need to find a way access the variables in the UIViewController class. check my other post its more clear there

Comment: You shouldn't do that. You should listen to the `UIKeyboardNotification` in the `UIViewController`. That's where that type of logic is supposed to go. From the `UIViewController`, you can then modify any of its view's subviews however you want when you receive the notification.

Comment: you can't. ScrollView changes the game :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think I can help you without writing the program for you. What I'm describing to you is perfectly possible.

Answer (score 0):

So much confusion, where to start? I really don't know. For what it's worth,

```
_myVar.text = "@"smth"
```

will obviously not compile, note the stray ".

```
_myVar.text = "@smth"
```

has a better chance of compiling.

Comment: that was a typo when i wrote this post to give an example.